# Making multiple assignments to objects named as strings

Tags: r, string, multiple-assignment

We can assign a value to a single object using that object's name - `assign("x", 1)` - and we can efficiently assign different values to multiple object thanks to the `zeallot` package - `c(x, y) %<-% c(1, 2)` - but can we do both? I basically just want to do `c("x", "y") %<-% c(1, 2)` and I can only think to do it in this lovely way:

```
invisible(mapply(function(i, j) assign(i, j, envir = .GlobalEnv), i = c("x", "y"), j = c(1, 2)))
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: just do `list2env(setNames(as.list(c(1,2)),c("x","y")),.GlobalEnv)` or even `list2env(as.list(setNames(c(1,2),c("x","y"))),.GlobalEnv)`

Comment: "Is there a better way?" - Can I ask why you're creating multiple free-floating objects in your global environment? I've seen many people here go down that route, and it almost always ends up coming back to making a list instead as `assign/get` becomes a nightmare eventually.

Comment: @Onyambu Thanks, that's pretty much the best I could have hoped for; I see that `list2env`'s help even says it can be used to "'multi-assign' from x into a pre-existing environment." Make that an answer and I'll accept it. @thelatemail I agree, though I suspect that some people are constrained to do it this way for various reasons, e.g. I'm looking to improving a colleague's code, they have these free-floating objects, and I just want to change one thing at a time here. Also, I mean, there IS a whole package just to create a multi-assign operator. And, Chollet uses it in Deep Learning with R.

Comment: I agree with @thelatemail that this is a bad practice, `put all the free-floating objects in a list` is more environment friendly and are recommended by FDA.

Comment: 'I see that list2env's help even says it can be used to "'multi-assign' from x into a pre-existing environment."' Note that this function was never intended for assignment into the global environment. That's a misuse.

Comment: @Roland You say to note that like the help file says that. I see nothing at all to suggest that this isn't one of the intended uses.

Comment: @DHW I remember R-core's Martin Mächler, the author himself, expressing this. Unfortunately, I can't find it right now.

Comment: @Roland Good enough for me :) Thanks

Comment: @DHW: Looks like you have your answer, but I still don't understand the question. 
 Could you clarify the purpose of this exercise? It's very abstract in its present form, and it would be helpful to know how you plan on applying it.

Comment: @Nettle I don't know how to better phrase the question; my title said what I was looking for, and it's what 'list2env' does, which I now know. By "better way," I meant a more concise, and presumably quicker, way, compared to the best 'apply'-based method I could write, which I provided. I don't want to get too deep into why I'm storing objects in the global environment here, as that's very much a separate question and I don't want to conflate the two.

Comment: @DHW: The question was clear. I'm just trying to figure out what it's for. Apparently others know, though, so I'll delete these comments to avoid distracting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list named elements of a list to an environment:

```
list2env(setNames(as.list(c(1,2)),c("x","y")),.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: I've marked this as the right answer, as it's probably still the best way and seems to work great, but note the above comments - it's apparently an unintended usage of `list2env`.