# Load model parameters from a data.frame into R environment

Tags: r

Example: I have the following parameter table:

```
df <- data.frame(vn=letters[1:3],values=1:3)
```

I want an automatic way to realize the following R code:

```
a <- 1
b <- 2
c <- 3
```

I know I can do the following to brute force it:

```
invisible(lapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) assign(df[x,1], df[x,2], envir=.GlobalEnv)))
```

But I am looking for a more beautiful way to do it.

Comment: And why do you want to do that?? This makes no sense. you can accomplish that by `list2env(as.list(tibble::deframe(df)), .GlobalEnv)` By why??

Comment: if you dont have `tibble` installed, you could run `list2env(as.list(do.call(setNames, unname(rev(df)))), .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: The reason is that I want to do simulations, and the parameters of the different simulations are from different user feed files. @onyambu Thanks for the awesome solution!

Comment: If you are trying to solve the problem by assigning objects to the global environment then you are not doing it correctly. I do not know what you are doing but I am sure you can access each element within the dataframe/matrix/vector/container that you have and use that for simulation. Consider not *polluting* the global environment

Comment: This is a good point,  I might want to modify the code to do it the way that you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: Would you want to post your comments as an answer to this question? So that I can accept it. @onyambu

Comment: There are alot of questions and answers just like the question you posted. Check for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51886899/making-multiple-assignments-to-objects-named-as-strings/51888320#51888320

Comment: Yoy can consider accepting the answer given already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `mapply` when you want to iterate over more than 1 list/vector in parallel:

```
with(df, mapply(assign, x = vn, value = values, MoreArgs = list(envir = .GlobalEnv)))
```